# How to get pure XMLHTTPRequest object in jQuery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, jquery-1.5

My code works fine in jquery 1.4 and i try upgrade it to 1.5.
But this part of code stop working - its standard beforeSend handler

```
beforeSend: function (xhr, options) {
//
__forced_abort = false;

//
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', on_progress, false);
xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', on_loaded, false);
xhr.addEventListener('abort', on_abort, false);
....
```

I know that in 1.5 havent really xhr - just jqXHR highlevel abstraction and seems to be jqXHR not have upload attributes.

Question: how get pure (old) xhr object in jQuery 1.5?

Answer (score 12):

If your beforeSend was global:

```
var oldXHR = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    var xhr = oldXHR();
    if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', on_progress, false);
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', on_loaded, false);
        xhr.addEventListener('abort', on_abort, false);
    }
    return xhr;
};
```

If your beforeSend was specific to a particular request:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', on_progress, false);
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', on_loaded, false);
            xhr.addEventListener('abort', on_abort, false);
        }
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

Comment: looks like it should be xhr: function(){

Answer (score 2):

Extending Raphaels answer to include percentages...

```
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) 
            {   

            }
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(){
                        var percent = 0;
                        var position = event.loaded || event.position; /*event.position is deprecated*/
                        var total = event.total;
                        if (event.lengthComputable) {
                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                        }

                        var percentVal = percent+ '%';
                        $('#progressBar').css('width',percentVal);
                        $('#uploadPercentage').html(' '+percentVal);
                    }, false);
                }
                return xhr;
            },                                  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr()

Comment: Use as? Can u give a little example?