# JQuery 1.4.2 XHR request net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm backend developer and pretty new in Javascript. I'm trying to upload files with old JQuery version (1.4.2), because there is no way to change it on current project.

This code works good on ANY JQuery version >= 1.5

```
$('#uploadform').submit(function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: '/uploader',
       data:formData,
       xhr: function() {
           var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
           if(myXhr.upload){
               //
           }
           return myXhr;
       },
       cache:false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,

       success: function(data){
           //
       },

       error: function(data){
           //
       }
   });
});
```

Each time a run it on JQuery 1.4.2, I have this error in Chrome (and other browsers):
`POST http://localhost:8080/uploader net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in `jquery-1.4.2.js:5252`

Is there a way to fix it without JQuery version change?

UPD

Here is my `<head>` section in html

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Remedy Uploader</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your `<script>` tags?

Comment: @DavidR yes, I added it in UPD

Comment: Try adding `type='text/javascript` to your `<script>` blocks.

Comment: Ok, just tried that. Sorry, didn't work for me.

Comment: try the below solution

Comment: Yes, already trying, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldXHR = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    var xhr = oldXHR();
    if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', on_progress, false);
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', on_loaded, false);
        xhr.addEventListener('abort', on_abort, false);
    }
    return xhr;
};

$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', on_progress, false);
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', on_loaded, false);
            xhr.addEventListener('abort', on_abort, false);
        }
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

check below URL

[How to get pure XMLHTTPRequest object in jQuery 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915671/how-to-get-pure-xmlhttprequest-object-in-jquery-1-5)

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to comment all code at http://localhost:8080/uploader and  just print a `hello` message. Then test it in browser, It must be working. If it does not work the fix it first, but when works then try following request as it is

with jquery 1.4.2 you can use same ajax request as it is used today

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //I commented followin gintentionally, you should check the 
    // before un-commenting this line
    //data : formData code 
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/uploader',
    success: function(data){alert(data)},
    error: function(err){ alert(er.responseText)};
});
```

Off course you will face no error

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean, but I ran this code (relplace formData code  with `new FormData(this);`

Result is `jquery-1.4.2.js:5437 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: You should get no error if you run it as it is. Problem could be with your `new FormData()` Yes i can guide about this problem, If exactly it is `FormData` then till me, i will help